# Meaning of QR-resultpoints in zxing

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

i'm working on a project to calculate the distance from an android phone to a qr code(which is always the same size) using zxing. I extracted the resultpoints, those 4 squares in the corners. The problem I'm having is I don't exactly what the coordinates of those resultpoints mean. On the one phone is matches the pixels of the display but on the other it represents something else (might have a scalefactor).
https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/ResultPoint.html
the getX() and getY() methods give me some sort of coordinates. Does anyone know what exactly the represent.

thanks flo

Comment: Sharing code would help others know what your problem is.

Comment: I added a link to library but I'm not having a problem with the code I just wanted to know if anyone knew their way around the zxing library.

Comment: They represent the location of the landmarks of the QR code measured in banacol banana's.